# GridLayout: get child's row/column number

Tags: android, row, indexof, android-gridlayout

How can I get the row-index and/or column-index of a `view` in a `GridLayout`?

---

Suppose you have a `TextView` that its direct parent is a `GridLayout`. Is there a way to understand what are the row-number and column-number of the `TextView` in the `GridLayout`?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple actually you can do that like this,
suppose your textView is v then

```
GridLayout parent = (GridLayout) v.getParent();
int x = parent.indexOfChild(v) / parent.getColumnCount();
int y = parent.indexOfChild(v) % parent.getColumnCount();
```

Yes, it's that simple

Comment: Oh! Thank you. Unfortunately, I don't remember this question (after more than 2 years). Thank you anyway. I hope this helps other people.

Comment: This answer is not right in many cases.  If you add the child views with one of the add methods that takes a GridLayout.LayoutParams argument, then the order of child view addition can be different than then row/column positioning of the views.